# ¿Cómo se configura adecuadamente los directorios donde se instalan un SDK, la versión del lenguaje de programación, directorio de librerisa y el path?

Tags: rstudio, rutas, packages

El problema es que creo que tengo instalado el lenguaje de programación en un directorio, y a parte el SKD (RStudio) Tiene instalada su vesión de R. No puedo actualizar paquetes en RStudio porque Rtools no lo tengo instalado en el directorio que reconoce RStudio, pero si que esta en el path, y por tanto tampoco se donde se instalan los paquetes.

Me gustaría entender los directorios de la carpeta de usuario y saber que es lo que se instala ahi relacionado con los lenguajes de programación, y que es lo que se instala en el directorio de archivos de programas.

Como veis, es un poco jaleo el que tengo asique si me aportais cualquier tipo de información de como se relaciónan, leen e instalan cada uno de estos elementos que he mencionado seríad e gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias

Comment: O sea, nos dices que no sabes cosas, pero no parece que las hayas buscado ni investigado, y pretendes que te demos respuestas como si fueramos google. No se si lo conseguiras o sera peor el remedio que la enfermedad, porque te pueden contestar variedad de cosas y algunas dispares entre si. Mírate [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funcionamos y así ayudarnos a ayudarte mejor. Tu pregunta actual es del tipo [No he hecho ninguna investigación previa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2878#2878) y solicitas que lo hagamos por ti.

Comment: Buenas tardes, puedo haberme equivocado a la hora de suponer cual es la dinamica. Como bien dices, las respuestas pueden ser dispares, y eso es lo que he encontrado en google, definciones sueltas que no se relacionan y no explican cual es el problema en la instalación que tenga.
Yo no pretendo que nadie invesigue por mi ni pierda tiempo Subi la pregunta para que alguien con conocimientos en directorios windows respondiese si quisiese ya que es algo bastante concreto. El que no sepa la respuesta lo logico es que no conteste, en lugar de indignarse.
Aun así, gracias por los enlaces.

Comment: No me indigno, no te preocupes, ni pretendo que tu te indignes tampoco. Quizás no soy amable pero soy conciso y me remito a las normas del sitio donde estamos para elaborar mis comentarios. Los enlaces que te he dado no son mios, son de la comunidad, y son para mejorar el funcionamiento del sitio y para que entre todos podamos ayudarnos mejor.  Si los lees con detenimiento lo entenderas perfectamente y modificarás tu pregunta acorde a ellos, si bien dices que efectivamente ya realizaste una investigación previa, entonces ponla para que veamos que no entedistes y si hicistes algo mal.

Comment: En algunas ocasiones, los que estamos dispuestos a ayudar, nos basamos en vuestras investigaciones previas para que quizás, sin tener ni idea previa de vuestro problema, o lenguaje implicado, veamos cosas que vosotros no hayais visto, ya sea porque tenemos más experiencia solucionando cualquier cosa, porque sepamos más idiomas y sepamos buscarlo en ellos, o por cualquier otro motivo, o porque se nos ocurren cosas que vosotros, por estar encallados, ya no se os ocurrian.  Sin investigación previa no nos ayudais a ayudaros y partir de cero nos cuesta mas a todos, tambien a los que saben del tema